# Netflix not working in Firefox, how to fix?

Tags: netflix

I just installed 14.04 LTS on my laptop. I tried to go on Netflix but it tells me to install silverlight but that does not work either. What are my options to get Netflix working on my laptop?

Answer (score 4):

You can install Firefox 49, which should have Netflix support, but there have been reports of some pretty serious graphical issues in that version.

Chrome will work just fine for Netflix, so I recommend you install that. You'll have to get it from Google's website. If you are using 32-bit Ubuntu, you can't install Chrome, unfortunately, and will have to try FF 49.

***Note:*** Installing the .deb file from Google will fail unless you install a dependency first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

---

Chromium is not a good option. It is similar to Chrome, but it doesn't have a lot of the proprietary stuff Chrome does, like Netflix compatibility.

Comment: I forget but does Chromium work for Netflix?

Comment: @edwinksl nope.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - FYI: My edit about the dependency is from experience

Comment: @AndroidDev oh yeah, I forgot about that. I usually just run `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get install -f` afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this:

[Now that I have Firefox 49, how do I watch Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-how-do-i-watch-netflix)

With firefox 49 and for now, changing the user-agent to a recent chrome version, netflix do work in firefox on linux

Answer (score 1):

**Netflix via Google**

The quick answer... Install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/). Netflix works naively on Ubuntu via Google's Builtin Netflix support.

**Netflix via Netflix Desktop**

Download the tar package from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/netflix-desktop).  A direct link to the current package is [Version 0.8.7](https://launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/trunk/0.8.7/+download/netflix-desktop.tar.gz).
Extract the package.  From the package directory run this these commands:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After that you can run `Netflix` seemlessly from Ubuntu's launch button.

**Netflix Via Firefox**
(tricky... in beta still being developed)

To upgrade to the latest version of Firefox from the developers repository perform these steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For Netflix change Firefox mode to User Agent mode, Google.

Comment: How would i get Firefox 49 if my computer is too slow to run Ubuntu in 64 bit?

Comment: @AlexDeSua I'll add the details to my question.